# Links não clicaveis

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, eu estou a criar a home de um site que tem um video em tela cheia que automáticamente da play mas com o video em tela cheia mesmo com o z-index os links não são clicáveis como podem ver, como faço para resolver isto?

```css
  *{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .bloco{
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
  }
  .links{
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   z-index: 100;
   position: fixed;
   display: flex;
  }
  .links label{
   z-index: 101;
   padding: 10px 0;
   flex-grow: 1;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all .4s;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Arial';
   font-size: 100%;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .links label:hover{
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  }
  .scroll input{
   display: none;
  }
  #home{
   background-color: #7fbd42;
  }
  #login{
   background-color: #7c2096;
  }
  #register{
   background-color: #414950;
  }
  #contact{
   background-color: #aaa;
  }
  #news{
   background-color: #7fbd42;
  }
  .scroll{
   display: flex;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .sections{
   transition: all .4s;
  }
  #rd_login:checked ~ .sections{
   margin-top: -100vh;
  }
  #rd_register:checked ~ .sections{
   margin-top: -200vh;
  }
  #rd_contact:checked ~ .sections{
   margin-top: -300vh;
  }
  #rd_news:checked ~ .sections{
   margin-top: -400vh;
  }
  #bg{
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   background-cover: cover;
  }
  #content{
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   padding: 30px;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: #000 2px 2px 2px;
   font-family: Arial;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="links">
 <label for="rd_pi">Pagina Inicial</label>
 <label for="rd_login">Login</label>
 <label for="rd_register">Registrar-me</label>
 <label for="rd_contact">Entrar em Contato</label>
 <label for="rd_news">Novidades</label>
</nav>
<div class="scroll">
 <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_pi" checked="true">
 <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_login">
 <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_register">
 <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_contact">
 <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_news">
<section class="sections">
 <section class="bloco" id="home">
 <video id="bg" src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" autoplay="" loop="true"></video>
 </section>
 <section class="bloco" id="login"></section>
 <section class="bloco" id="register"></section>
 <section class="bloco" id="contact"></section>
 <section class="bloco" id="news"></section>
</section>
</div>
```

estou a seguir o seguinte tutorial : [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiI6PbD6Ei4)

Comment: A sua lista de navegação não tem `<a>` com respetivos atributos `href` logo não tem links mas sim textos apenas.

Comment: Esta pagina não trabalha com <a> mas sim com <label> e cada label esta associado a um radio button que no css quando checado da um margin-top para o conteúdo que o usuário quer ver, seguindo o modelo de one-page

Comment: O problema está  `position:fixed` do video, que o faz estar sempre por cima de tudo. Para alem disso `background-cover` não existe, e seria `background-size` mas apenas aplicável ao background mesmo. Os "links" sempre foram clicaveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema principal era que vc estava usando `position:fixed` no vídeo, não tem muita a ver com *label*, *link* nem nada disso...

Veja qua agora eu coloquei com `position:absolute` e funcionou.

**OBS:** Aqui não funciona direito pq o *Snippet* do Stackoverflow é muito estreito, mas na sua página vai funcionar normal.

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .bloco{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
    }
    .links{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
    }
    .links label{
        z-index: 101;
        padding: 10px 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all .4s;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        font-size: 100%;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .links label:hover{
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    }
    .scroll input{
        display: none;
    }
    #home{
        background-color: #7fbd42;
        position: relative;
    }
    #login{
        background-color: #7c2096;
    }
    #register{
        background-color: #414950;
    }
    #contact{
        background-color: #aaa;
    }
    #news{
        background-color: #7fbd42;
    }
    .scroll{
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .sections{
        transition: all .4s;
    }
    #rd_login:checked ~ .sections{
        margin-top: -100vh;
    }
    #rd_register:checked ~ .sections{
        margin-top: -200vh;
    }
    #rd_contact:checked ~ .sections{
        margin-top: -300vh;
    }
    #rd_news:checked ~ .sections{
        margin-top: -400vh;
    }
    #bg{
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #content{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        padding: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: #000 2px 2px 2px;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="links">
    <label for="rd_pi">Pagina Inicial</label>
    <label for="rd_login">Login</label>
    <label for="rd_register">Registrar-me</label>
    <label for="rd_contact">Entrar em Contato</label>
    <label for="rd_news">Novidades</label>
</nav>
<div class="scroll">
    <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_pi" checked="true">
    <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_login">
    <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_register">
    <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_contact">
    <input type="radio" name="grupo_menu" id="rd_news">
    <section class="sections">
        <section class="bloco" id="home">
            <video id="bg" src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" autoplay="" loop="true"></video>
        </section>
        <section class="bloco" id="login"></section>
        <section class="bloco" id="register"></section>
        <section class="bloco" id="contact"></section>
        <section class="bloco" id="news"></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de utilizar um label use um **a href**

Segue um exemplo para entender

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Comment: O problema é que o <a> não permite marcar/desmarcar radio buttons https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QiI6PbD6Ei4

Comment: seguis te tudo ao pormenor do tutorial??

Comment: sim mas no tutorial ele coloca uma imagem e eu coloquei um video e aproveitei o código de um outro tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1BMxu_kAE4

Comment: ve se consegues com isto - https://codepen.io/saladeestudo/pen/mErOkg

Comment: o problema não ta nos links pois se eu tirar a tag video ele funciona

Comment: ja verificou se a tag video funciona com essa propriedade ? É que nem sempre funcionam todas as tags